# Oracle Lag function to derive sum of previous 3 months balance

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to calculate the sum of previous 3 months balance. i'M trying following code, which isn't working. can you please help

my data set

```
DATE    ID  BAL        
201701  1   1004768.32  
201702  2   1126215.77  
201703  3   1135731.08  
201704  4   1383859.84  
201705  5   1828847.51
201706  6   1520265.46
```

Below is the sql i'm using to calculate SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL. However, The issue is i'm getting previous 3 month bal but NOT SUM

```
 ROUND(LAG(SUM(BAL), 3) over (partition by ID order by DATE),2) AS SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL.
```

I also tried the following,

```
ROUND(SUM(lag(BAL,3)) over (partition by ID order by DATE),2) AS SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL-- which is getting below error

ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
30484. 00000 -  "missing window specification for this function"
*Cause:    All window functions should be followed by window specification,
           like <function>(<argument list>) OVER (<window specification>)
```

Below is the incorrect result i'm getting.

```
    DATE    ID      BAL     SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL -- incorrect
    201701  1   1004768.32  
    201702  2   1126215.77  
    201703  3   1135731.08  
    201704  4   1383859.84  1004768.32
    201705  5   1828847.51  1126215.77
    201706  6   1520265.46  1135731.08
```

my expected result is as below

```
    DATE    ID  BAL        SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL--correct
    201701  1   1004768.32  
    201702  2   1126215.77  
    201703  3   1135731.08  
    201704  4   1383859.84  3266715.17
    201705  5   1828847.51  3645806.69
    201706  6   1520265.46  4348438.43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `SUM` as an analytic function with an appropriate window here:

```
SELECT
    "DATE",
    ID,
    BAL,
    CASE WHEN LAG(BAL, 3) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE") IS NOT NULL
         THEN SUM(BAL) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
         ELSE NULL END AS SUM_PREV_3_MNTH_BAL
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

We first check if the balance exists in table from 3 months earlier.  If not, then we just report `NULL` for that 3 month sum (this happens for January through March inclusive of 2017).  If the balance *does* exists, then we take the 3 month sum.  Note that the window we use here is between 3 and 1 rows preceding.

Comment: Thank you, How do i get this working using the LAG function?

Comment: The answer I have given is the best way of which I know (and maybe the only way I know).

Comment: Sir I'm getting error as "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Then you're not running my query, which is working in the demo using the sample data you provided above.

Comment: you r right.. i have few extra columns, but i'm it is complaining abt GROUP by clause, with the suggest syntax of using SUM on a BAL column

Comment: Again, you're not actually using my code.  Start with my demo, and transform it into what you need, checking after each change that you didn't break it.

Comment: @stackuser, If you have problems with a different table it's better to ask a different question.